# Keys getting set to same value in dictionary on iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have his really simple dictionary, called `mydict` I am iterating over it and setting new nested keys. For some reason, each parent key is set on each iteration. Each `random` key should have a randomly generated number. It seems to be some issue with this `dict.fromkeys(myset, {})` as if I hardcode it then things seem fine. I've tried `copy` and `deepcopy` with no luck.

```
import random
myset = ['A', 'B', 'C']
mydict = dict.fromkeys(myset, {})
for k, v in mydict.items():
    mydict[k]['random'] = random.random()
print mydict
```

output looks like this:

```
{'A': {'random': 0.09458900537947934}, 'C': {'random': 0.09458900537947934}, 'B': {'random': 0.09458900537947934}}
```

Comment: Because you are using the same dictionary inside `mydict`. Try to change to `mydict={'A': {}, 'B': {}, 'C': {}}` and it will work

Comment: @BlackBear I realize that as I mentioned hardcoding. This is just a simple example, and the `mydict` needs to be derived from the set, which I why I was trying things with `copy` and `deepcopy`.

Comment: That error was surprising to me. I still don't understand why this is happening. After all, when I do `{ k: {} for k in myset } == dict.fromkeys(myset, {})`, it returns True. However, the first one works, and not the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize your `mydict` with tuple consisting of keys and values:

```
import random

myset = ['A', 'B', 'C']
mydict = dict(zip(myset, iter(lambda: {}, None)))

for k, v in mydict.items():
    mydict[k]['random'] = random.random()

print(mydict)
```

Prints:

```
{'A': {'random': 0.17573941764965995}, 'B': {'random': 0.7591872462452937}, 'C': {'random': 0.6027577677034227}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import random

myset = ['A', 'B', 'C']

mydict = {}

for k in myset:
    temp = {'random':random.random()}
    mydict[k] = temp

print (mydict)
```

It is easier to make a empty dict and then populate it

output:

```
{'A': {'random': 0.8487768382668905}, 'B': {'random': 0.3199770033314223}, 'C': {'random': 0.9574897543475179}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get behavior you're observins is you call `dict.fromkeys` function, which takes value (empty dictionary object in your case) and assign it to every key. So all your keys in `mydict` points to **the same** value (dictionary). For every key in your for loop you update **the same** dictionary with newer and newer `random` key. If you want to see more, do:

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
  print('%s %s' % (k, id(v)))
```

you will see, that every value in your `mydict` dictionary is exactly the same dict. For working code try @okawo answer.